# Apache 301 redirect rewrite / to /en and keep /fr to /fr keeping all passed variables

Tags: wordpress, apache, mod-rewrite, redirect, multilingual

I have a bilingual Wordpress site that I am changing the domain for and the following redirect works great.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^newdomain\.com$
RewriteRule ^ http://newdomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

The problem is I would like to have

```
olddomain.com/one/two/three
```

to redirect to

```
newdomain.com/en/one/two/three
```

but keep

```
olddomain.com/fr/one/two/three
```

redirecting to

```
newdomain.com/fr/one/two/three
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place this rule just below `RewriteBase` line in your main WP .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^en/ http://newdomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^(en|fr)/ http://newdomain.com/fr%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```

Comment: one/two/three was just an example. It will always be different. I pretty much need a if else. If en go to en if not en go to fr

Comment: sorry en for english. domain.com/en/year/month/postname should go to newdomain.com/en/year/month/postname else if domain.com/year/month/postname (no en) then redirect to newdomain.com/fr/year/month/postname

Comment: the year/month/postname is just an example, I hope to have this work for all pages posts categories etc.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've accepted your answer because it works but would you be able explain what's happening. I find the Rewrite Rules especially confusing with the language codes before the URL.

Comment: Glad it worked out. Rule1 matches anything that starts with `/en/` and redirects to `http://newdomain.com/URI` while Rule2 matches anything that is not `/en/` OR `/fr/` and redirects to `http://newdomain.com/fr/URI`

Comment: Thanks. I got the logic after starring at it a bit longer. Used to seeing the condition in the rewritecond not the rewrite rule